# Set Date and time of application in serial Communication C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm working on WPF application.

My application is talking to another application through comport using serial Communication.
Another application is sending command to my application to set date and time of my application.
I have created class for Date and Time like this:

```
public class MyApplicationDateTime
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Year Varibale
    /// </summary>
    private UInt16 year;

    /// <summary>
    /// Minute Varibale
    /// </summary>
    private byte month;

    /// <summary>
    /// Day Varibale
    /// </summary>
    private byte day;

    /// <summary>
    /// Hour Varibale
    /// </summary>
    private byte hour;

    /// <summary>
    /// Minute Varibale
    /// </summary>
    private byte minute;

    /// <summary>
    /// Second Varibale
    /// </summary>
    private byte second;

  /// <summary>
  /// Initializes a new instance of the DeviceDateTime class
  /// </summary>
    public DeviceDateTime()
    {

    }

    #region Property
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Year Value
    /// </summary>
    public UInt16 Year
    {
        get { return this.year = Convert.ToUInt16(DateTime.Now.Year); }
        set { this.year = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Month Value
    /// </summary>
    public byte Month
    {
        get { return this.month = Convert.ToByte(DateTime.Now.Month); }
        set { this.month = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Day Value
    /// </summary>
    public byte Day
    {
        get { return this.day = Convert.ToByte(DateTime.Now.Day); }
        set { this.day = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Hour Value
    /// </summary>
    public byte Hour
    {
        get { return this.hour = Convert.ToByte(DateTime.Now.Hour); }
        set { this.hour = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Minute Value
    /// </summary>
    public byte Minute
    {
        get { return this.minute = Convert.ToByte(DateTime.Now.Minute); }
        set { this.minute = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Second Value
    /// </summary>
    public byte Second
    {
        get { return this.second = Convert.ToByte(DateTime.Now.Second); }
        set { this.second = value; }
    }
```

I'm getting Date time and try to set My application Date and time.
Will It set date and time of my application through property I have create in class?
Is there any best way to do?

Comment: Not an answer: what's wrong with using `DateTime` to hold your application's date/time?

Comment: You should re-phrase your question, it's really difficult to understand what you want exactly to do. Also, as @Ricard said, why aren't your using `DateTime` ?

Comment: Well, it would set field values through properties, but next time you will call getters, the values will be overridden by "actual" (`DateTime.Now`) values.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider just one property implementation:

> ```
> public UInt16 Year
> {
>    get { return this.year = Convert.ToUInt16(DateTime.Now.Year); }
>    set { this.year = value; }
> ```
>
> }

Every time you get this property, it will reset it from the system's current date.

Thus you'll *never* see any value you set.

Suggestion: don't do anything extra in your properties: remove the private fields, and use automatic properties:

```
public UInt16 Year { get; set; }
public byte Month { get; set; }
public byte Day { get; set; }
// …
```

And then have a separate method to reset to the current date/time:

```
public void ResetToSystemTime() {
  var now = DateTime.Now;
  Year = (UInt16) now.Year;
  // …
}
```